# Line Plot of Specific Columns from Pyspark Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pyspark, linechart

I have the data below and need to create a line chart of x = Date and y = count.

The code I used to create the dataframe below was from another dataframe.

```
df7=df7.select("*",
concat(col("Month"),lit("/"),col("Year")).alias("Date"))
df7.show()
```

[image]

I've imported matplotlib.pyplot as plt and am still getting errors.

The code to plot I used in different variations as below:

```
df.plot(x = 'Date', y = 'Count')

df.plot(kind = 'line')
```

I keep getting this error though:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'plt'/'plot'
```

Comment: I tried plot as well and get the same error. AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'plot'

Comment: Please create a [reprex]. Include code, error, and the data *as text*.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I copy and paste the table from pandas the format never follows.

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) may be helpful.

Comment: you need to convert the dataframe from spark dataframe to pandas dataframe.
try df_pd= df.toPandas()
and then run the plot on df_pd.

Comment: That worked! Thank you. The X axis doesn't show any text but i think that's because there are a lot of dates.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that using `df_pd= df.toPandas()` is sometimes expensive, and if you deal with a high number of records like a scale of M, you might face [OOM error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70513641/azure-databricks-oom-error-that-causes-the-connection-to-the-python-repl-to-be-c) in *Databricks* medium or your session could be crashed due to a lack of RAM memory of the drive. Long story short, by using `toPandas()`, in fact, you are not using spark-based or distributed computation resources anymore! So alternatively, you can follow below approach:
So let's start with a simple example:

```py
import time
import datetime as dt
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import dayofmonth, dayofweek
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType, TimestampType, DateType

dict2  = [("2021-08-11 04:05:06", 10),
         ("2021-08-12 04:15:06", 17),
         ("2021-08-13 09:15:26", 25),
         ("2021-08-14 11:04:06", 68),
         ("2021-08-15 14:55:16", 50),
         ("2021-08-16 04:12:11", 2),

  ]

schema = StructType([ 

    StructField("timestamp",     StringType(),    True), \
    StructField("count",         IntegerType(),    True), \
  ])
 
#create a Spark dataframe
sqlCtx = SQLContext(sc)
sdf = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(data=dict2,schema=schema)
sdf.printSchema()
sdf.show(truncate=False)

#Generate date and timestamp
new_df = sdf.withColumn('timestamp',    F.to_timestamp("timestamp", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").cast(TimestampType())) \
            .withColumn('date',         F.to_date("timestamp",      "yyyy-MM-dd").cast(DateType())) \
            .select('timestamp', 'date', 'count') 

new_df.show(truncate = False)  

#root
# |-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)
# |-- count: integer (nullable = true)

#+-------------------+-----+
#|timestamp          |count|
#+-------------------+-----+
#|2021-08-11 04:05:06|10   |
#|2021-08-12 04:15:06|17   |
#|2021-08-13 09:15:26|25   |
#|2021-08-14 11:04:06|68   |
#|2021-08-15 14:55:16|50   |
#|2021-08-16 04:12:11|2    |
#+-------------------+-----+

#+-------------------+----------+-----+
#|timestamp          |date      |count|
#+-------------------+----------+-----+
#|2021-08-11 04:05:06|2021-08-11|10   |
#|2021-08-12 04:15:06|2021-08-12|17   |
#|2021-08-13 09:15:26|2021-08-13|25   |
#|2021-08-14 11:04:06|2021-08-14|68   |
#|2021-08-15 14:55:16|2021-08-15|50   |
#|2021-08-16 04:12:11|2021-08-16|2    |
#+-------------------+----------+-----+
```

Now you need to `collect()` the values of the columns you want to reflect your plot in the absence of Pandas; of course, this is expensive and takes (a long) time in big data records, but it works. Now you can apply one of the following ways:

```py
#for big\high # of records
xlabels = new_df.select("timestamp").rdd.flatMap(list).collect()
ylabels = new_df.select("count").rdd.flatMap(list).collect()

#for limited # of records
xlabels   = [val.timestamp  for val in new_df.select('timestamp').collect()]
ylabels   = [val.count      for val in new_df.select('count').collect()]
```

To plot:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as md

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
plt.plot(xlabels,     ylabels,   color='blue',    label="event's count") #, marker="o"
plt.scatter(xlabels,  ylabels,   color='cyan', marker='d', s=70)

plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.ylabel('Event counts \n# of records', fontsize=15)
plt.xlabel('timestamp', fontsize=15)
plt.title('Events over time', fontsize=15, color='darkred', weight='bold')
plt.legend(['# of records'], loc='upper right')

plt.show()
```

[image: img]

Based on comments, I assumed due to having lots of records that are printed under x-axis timestamps are not readable like the below pic:

[image: img]

To resolve this, you need to use the following approach to arrange x-axis ticks properly so that they would not plot on top of each other or ultimately side-by-side:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=xlabels
y=ylabels

#Note 1: if you use Pandas dataFrame after .toPandas()
#x=df['timestamp']
#y=df['count']

##Note 2: if you use Pandas dataFrame after .toPandas()
# convert the datetime column to a datetime type and assign it back to the column
#df.timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp)
#verify timestamp column type is datetime64[ns] using print(df.info()) 

fig, ax = plt.subplots( figsize=(12,8))

plt.plot(x, y)

ax.legend(['# of records'])
ax.set_xlabel('Timestamp')
ax.set_ylabel('Event counts \n# of records')

# beautify the x-labels
import matplotlib.dates as md

plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
myFmt = md.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)

plt.show()
plt.close()
```

[image: img]